# Upload and View Files ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Knowledgebase KB, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var KBFilePath = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(KB.KnowledgebaseTitle);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Resources/KBArticles"), fileName + ".pdf");
                KBFilePath = path;
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            KB.KnowledgebaseLink = KBFilePath;
            db.Knowledgebases.Add(KB);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        else
        {
            return View();
        }
```

The link is the filepath which is stored in the DB which starts with C:/

On another page I can view the contents of the record. When I click on the link to which its saved on the C:/, Chrome says 'Failed to load local resource'. I am saving into the Resources folder which is part of my ASP.NET app directory. Anyway around this?

EDIT
The page is served from this View:

```
public ActionResult Suggestions(String Tag)
{
      return View();
}
```

EDIT 2 - I put the changes in my view:

```
@{
string tag = "<td><a href=" + "~/Content/Files/" + ">" + item.Title.Replace(" ", "") + ".pdf" + "</a>" + "</td>";
 }
 @Html.Raw(tag)
```

The requested file in the browser address bar is

```
http://localhost:62165/Incident/~/Content/Files/
```

Now I get a HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found error

Comment: I had the same problem when the file is an image. Make sure that they have extension.

Comment: Yes all the uploaded files have the .pdf extension

Comment: Maybe the wrong type of slash. It seems obvious but it happens a lot. Urls .../.../. Absolute paths ...\...\

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do I use back slashes in the Server.MapPath? I am running locally in VC 2013

Comment: Server.MapPath is fine that way. I mean that the link should have / if the path is relative to the Web App root directory (as it should be). If the path is absolute to your file system it should have \. But you don't want to use links that points to your file system, file uploads should be stored in db, App_Data folder or any other folder inside your App root folder.

Comment: Yes the link does contain / and not \. I did test saving to the App_data folder but same problem.

Comment: This is the answer to the deleted comment: You mean, not standard. I have Chrome 32.0 and it works. Click on the link starts download.

Comment: Please try to keep your comments so people can follow the flow of the question. Otherwise we can find answers to non existing questions in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to save the files in Content folder. You can create a sub folder Content/Files. Put you files there. Then generate the links like:

`<a href="~/Content/Files/file1.pdf">File1</a>`

or use the download attribute if you want to download directly:

`<a href="~/Content/Files/file1.pdf" download>File1</a>`.

Most web servers are configured to deny requests for content outside the content folder. This can be modified in the config file but is easier (and safer) if you use the content folder. *This is based on my experience, if someone think that I'm wrong please let me know to fix my answer. I'm always glad to learn something new.*

**EDIT 1: How to build the `a` tag dynamically**

In the view you need a string variable `link` that holds the text of the link you want to show and another variable `path` to hold the path (maybe both are loaded from db in the controller). Then you can build the tag manually like this:

```
@{
    string tag = "<a href=" + path + ">" + link + "</a>";
}

@Html.Raw(tag)
```

**EDIT 2: Dealing with spaces in Url.**

You need to use `Html.Content` to get the right relative Url.

```
@{
    string link = item.Title;
    string path = Url.Content("~/Content/Files/") + link.Replace(" ", "%20") + ".pdf";
    string tag = "<a href=" + path + ">" + link + "</a>";
}

@Html.Raw(tag)
```

Comment: How do I href if the links or stored in the db dynamically? Every link will be different?

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 You can build the `a` tag yourself and render it in the view.

Comment: I edited my post to add the view. Could you expand on your comment please?

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 Read my updated answer. Let me know for any missing character. I'm writing this directly into the answer.

Comment: Did that and replaced path with item.Link and link with item.titlee and it couldn't find the requested file when I clicked the link. But in the browser bar its trying to go to : /Content/Files/Clear a Printer Jammed

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 The problem is that `item.title` contains spaces. If you want to keep spaces, then replace them by `%20`. I strongly recommend that you replace them with a symbol like `+` instead.

Comment: It says my model class 'Knowledgebase' does not contain a definition for Content

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 `Content` is a helper method of `Html` class, you are trying to use it as a method of your model. Try to stick to the example. I have to leave for now. I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: No I'm trying to use it with the HTML class. It is not a method of Html.

Comment: I've replaced Html.Content with Html.AttributeEncode and run that but doesn't work

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 I'm so sorry. I typed `Html` in place of `Url`. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 19):

This is a full example that shows how to upload files and put them available for download through links.

Create an empty MVC Project.
**I use MVC 4 but it should work with MVC 5.**

**Controller:**

In the `HomeController` we are going to have a single action `Index` that will show the list of files available for download and the option for uploading new files.

Action `Index` GET:

- Locate the path to 'Content/Files/'.
- Get the list of all files in that folder.
- Use that list as the model of the `Index` view.

Action `Index` POST:

- Locate the path to 'Content/Files/'.
- Create a temporary array to store the content of the file.
- Read the content to the buffer.
- Write the content to a file in folder 'Content/Files/'.

Code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/");

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        var files = dir.EnumerateFiles().Select(f => f.Name);

        return View(files);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"), file.FileName);

        var data = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);

        using (var sw = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            sw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

**View:**

In the view we need to generate a list with links to the files. Here we need to take care of file names that contains spaces and replace them with '%20'.

The form to upload a file is simple. Just an input tag to get the file and one button to send the form.

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Files</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var fName in Model)
    {
        var name = fName;
        var link = @Url.Content("~/Content/Files/") + name.Replace(" ", "%20");

        <li>
            <a href="@link">@name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="File" name="file" id="file" value="Choose File"/>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    }
</div>
```

The result should be:

[image: Index view]

Comment: What if I wanted to create multiple folders (lets say 5) and my view has 5 different columns to view each row of pdf's. But I only have 1 controller for the 1 page view. Is there a way to tweak the controller to allow each different area it's own content path?

Comment: @majache You can create the markup for 5 folders in the view and use 5 different paths for storing files. You will need to change the model of the view from `IEnumerable<string>` to a model that defines an `IEnumerable<string>` for each folder you want to display.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the files in the folder from the web view?

Answer (score 1):

First the Create View <

```
<div class="form-group"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageData, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
  <div class="col-md-10"> <input name="Image" type="file" /> 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageData) 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Then the Controller Create Action

```
public ActionResult Create(ArtWork artwork, HttpPostedFileBase image) { 
  if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
    if (image != null) { //attach the uploaded image to the object before saving to Database 
      artwork.ImageMimeType = image.ContentLength; 
      artwork.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength]; 
      image.InputStream.Read(artwork.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength); //Save image to file 
      var filename = image.FileName; 
      var filePathOriginal = Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Originals"); 
      var filePathThumbnail = Server.MapPath("/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails"); 
      string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePathOriginal, filename); 
      image.SaveAs(savedFileName); //Read image back from file and create thumbnail from it 
      var imageFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Originals"), filename); 

      using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile)) 
      using (var newImage = new Bitmap(100, 100)) 
      using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) 
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) { 
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality; 
        graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)); 
        newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); 
        var thumbNew = File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png"); 
        artwork.ArtworkThumbnail = thumbNew.FileContents; 
      } 
    } 

    //Save model object to database 
    db.ArtWorks.Add(artwork); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
  } 
  return View(artwork); 
}
```

Then a get Image or GetThumbnail method

```
public FileContentResult GetThumbnailImage(int artworkId) { 
  ArtWork art = db.ArtWorks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ArtWorkId == artworkId); 
  if (art != null) { 
    return File(art.ArtworkThumbnail, art.ImageMimeType.ToString()); 
  } else { 
    return null; 
  } 
}
```

And here for the display in the view

```
<td> <img src="@Url.Action("GetThumbnailImage", "Artwork", new { Model.ArtWorkId })" alt="Artwork Image" /> </td>
```